# mysql: unrecognized statement type. (near WITH)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create cte statement in phpmyadmin but phpmyadmin shows error on left 'unrecognized statement type. (near WITH)'.
I really don't understand whats wrong with this code or MySql/phpmyadmin or any others configuration.

PHP Version 7.2.0.
MySQL 5.0.12

[click for snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n9jk.png)

Comment: Seems like it's time to upgrade. (Was introduced in MySQL 8.0.1)

Comment: what do you mean 'upgrade'? what should i specially upgrade?

Comment: Your MySQL installation, to version 8.0.1 or later.

Comment: Jarlh means the syntax (specifically with WITH)  you're trying to use was only introduced in MySQL 8, but you're trying to run it on MySQL 5. So if you want to use that syntax, you'll have to upgrade your MySQL server to version 8.

Comment: Oh I would have doubts about the feasibility of going from 5.0.12 to 8 in a single step. I would google mysql recursion for alternatives to with.

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin(xampp php version 7.2.0), not the Oracle MySql @jarlh

Comment: @Akash phpmyadmin is just a GUI application used to access a MySQL/MariaDB server, it's irrelevant to this issue. The MySQL/MariaDB version is what's important. As you posted yourself, your version is too old to be used with the syntax you want. So either re-write your query, or upgrade your server. P.S. are you actually using MariaDB or mySQL. Your question says mySQL but then in the comments you mention XAMPP which normally comes with mariaDB instead.

Comment: you'll need at least mariadb 10.2 to support this syntax, if that's what you're using. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/

Comment: i m using xampp 7.2.0 / PHP 7.2.0 and everything is default the database, control panel and everything else so what should i upgrade now?

Comment: xampp just installs the individual components AFAIK so you still ought to be able to upgrade each part separately. As we said you need to upgrade the database server (whether that be mySQL or mariaDB, which you still haven't confirmed despite being asked) to a version which supports your syntax. This might help, if you're using Windows: http://www.mynotebucket.com/update-mysql-under-xmpp/ . I'm sure instructions for other O/Ses can be found online too. TBH though if you are this unsure about what you're doing, you might be better just finding a way to re-write your query as P.Salmon suggested.

Comment: 4 years later, still nothing lmao

Answer (score 1):

**WITH** keyword (Common Table Expressions) are not yet supported by phpmyadmin's sql parser yet
can check it [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165).

Until that to use the same syntax use other alternatives tools like sequal pro for macos etc or sql command line itself.